# Unable to implement methods from a class that implements an interface?

Tags: java, methods, interface, scope, polymorphism

I'm starting to think I don't understand polymorphism quite like I thought I did.

I have the following situation:

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        interTest myTest = new classTest();
        myTest.classMethod();

    }
}
```

With the given interface:

```
public interface interTest {

    public boolean checkBoolean();
    public void method();

}
```

And then the concrete class:

```
public class classTest implements interTest{

    public classTest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void classMethod(){
        System.out.println("fail");
    }

    // Both method() and checkBoolean() are overridden here & do nothing.

    }

}
```

The Oracle documents demonstrate implementing an interface and then adding additional methods, or even implementing multiple interfaces (and therefore including methods that aren't in one of the interfaces) and I thought this was commonplace, until I ran into issues trying to do this myself.

In this instance I am not able to access `classMethod` because it is not inside the interface.

```
The method classMethod() is undefined for the type interTest
```

What am I not understanding about polymorphism? I thought declaring a variable in the form:

```
Interface object = new ConcreteClass();
```

created an interface object that could access ConcreteClass() methods. This is how you make multiple objects that are all of the same type (interface) and can fit in a type specific list but are different.

Why can't I call the `myTest.classMethod()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At compile time, methods are resolve based on the type of the expression they are invoked on.

In

```
Interface object = new ConcreteClass();
object.classMethod();
```

the method `classMethod()` is invoked on a variable of type `Interface` which doesn't declare or have a visible method named `classMethod()`.

The type `ConcreteClass` does declare such a method, so you could do

```
ConcreteClass object = new ConcreteClass();
object.classMethod();
```

or even

```
((ConcreteClass) object).classMethod();
```

if you were certain `object` was referencing a `ConcreteClass` object. Otherwise you would get a `ClassCastException` at run time.

---

Basically, you need to learn the difference between compile time type and static type versus run time type and dynamic type.

In

```
Interface object = new ConcreteClass();
```

the static type of `object` is `Interface`. At run time, the variable is referencing an object of type `ConcreteClass`, so its run time type is `ConcreteClass`.

Comment: So when/why would you do something like `List myList = new ArrayList()`? Is there a better way to accomplish this? IE via an abstract class and extensions?

Comment: @leigero Go through this question: [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) If you want to invoke a method, you need to invoke it on an expression that resolves to a type that declares such a method. How you do that depends on your use case.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Good to know this wasn't quite as obvious as I thought it was (at least not to me).